# Replace div element with jQuery and select it from jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a `div` that loads initially based on whether a sound option on my website is toggled on or off.

```php
<?php
    if  (isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['sound']==1))
    echo "
    <div id = 'soundToggle'>
          <form id = 'soundOffForm'>
            <p> Sound is currently on. </p>
            <center><input type = 'submit' value ='Turn Off Sound' /></center>
          </form>
    </div>
        ";
    else if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['sound']==0))
    echo "
    <div id = 'soundToggle'>
          <form id = 'soundOnForm'>
            <p> Sound is currently off. </p>
            <center><input type = 'submit' value = 'Turn On Sound' /></center>
          </form>
    </div>
        ";
?>
```

This always works when I refresh the page.

However, I am trying to use jQuery to reload the soundToggle div with the div that turns either the sound on or off (via form submission) when I submit the current form inside the soundToggle div.

index.php:

```
<?php session_start();
#session_regenerate_id(true);
include ("dbconfig.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['introd']))
{   
    header("Location: intro.php");
}
 ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "site.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.php?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
    <script>

            function validatingForm(){
                var x;
                var y;
                var e;
                var p;

                x = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('password').value;
                e = document.getElementById('errorMsg');
                p = document.getElementById('errorPass');

                if(x !="" && y !=""){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == ""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!=""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!=""){
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }
        function validatingSignUpForm(){
                var x;
                var y;
                var e;
                var p;

                x = document.getElementById('newonameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('newopassword').value;
                e = document.getElementById('newoerrorMsg');
                p = document.getElementById('newoerrorPass');

                if(x !="" && y !=""){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == ""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!=""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!=""){
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }
        function addValidate(){
                var x;
                var y;
                var z;
                var e;
                var p;
                var r;

                x = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('password').value;
                z = document.getElementById('role').value;
                e = document.getElementById('errorMsg');
                p = document.getElementById('errorPass');
                r = document.getElementById('errorRole');

                if(x !="" && y !="" && z !="empty"){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == "" & z == "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x !="" && y == "" & z == "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!="" && z == "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == "" && z != "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!="" && z != "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!="" && z != "empty"){
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }


        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
                <?php

                if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
                        /* user is logged in */
                        echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Hi, ". $_SESSION['user'] . "! Welcome to the site!</p>";
                else
                        /* user is NOT logged in*/
                        echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Please Login:</p>
                                        <form action='welcome.php' method='post'>
                                            <center><b id = 'errorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                            <input type='text' id='nameCheck' name = 'username' /></center>
                                            <br />
                                            <center><b id='errorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='password' id ='password' name = 'password'/></center>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <center><input type='submit' value='Log In' onClick='return validatingForm()'/></center>
                                        </form>

                              <p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> OR Sign Up:</p>
                                        <form action='sign_up.php' method='post'>
                                            <center><b id = 'newoerrorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                            <input type='text' id='newonameCheck' name = 'addusername' /></center>
                                            <br />
                                            <center><b id='newoerrorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='password' id ='newopassword' name = 'addpassword'/></center>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <center><input type='submit' value='Sign Up' onClick='return validatingSignUpForm()'/></center>
                                        </form>
                                        ";
                ?>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {

                    /*query user db */
                    $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users");

                    /* Assume there is a recordset and create the table */
                    echo "<center>
                            <h1> User List:</h1>
                            <table border='1'>
                            <tr>
                            <td><b>User ID</b></td>
                            <td><b>Username</b></td>
                            <td><b>Password</b></td>
                            <td><b>Options</b></td>
                            </tr>";

                            /* loop through recordset - new row for each user */
                            while( $record = $user_rs->fetch_object() ){
                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>" . $record->id . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->username . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->password . "</td>
                                        <td><a href='remove_user.php?id=" . $record->id . "'>Delete</a></td>  
                                    </tr>";
                            }
                            /* Close the table */
                            echo "
                                </table>
                            </center>
                            <br />";
                            }
                else if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'user') {

                    /*query user db */
                    $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");

                    /* Assume there is a recordset and create the table */
                    echo "<center>
                            <h1> Your Profile:</h1>
                            <table border='1'>
                            <tr>
                            <td><b>User ID</b></td>
                            <td><b>Username</b></td>
                            <td><b>Password</b></td>
                            </tr>";

                            /* take one row for user only */
                            $record = $user_rs->fetch_object();
                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>" . $record->id . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->username . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->password . "</td>
                                    </tr>";

                            /* Close the table */
                            echo "
                                </table>
                            </center>
                            <br />";
                            }
                #else {
                    #do nothing
                #   }
            ?>
            <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role']=="admin")
                    echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Add User:</p>
                                <form action='add_user.php' method='post' onSubmit='return addValidate();' style = 'border: 2px grey solid; padding: 5px'>
                                    <b id='errorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                    <input type='text' id='nameCheck' name='addusername'/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b id='errorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='password' id='password' name='addpassword'/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b id='errorRole'>Role:</b> <select name='addrole' id='role' >
                                    <option value='empty'>Select Role</option>
                                    <option value='admin'>Admin</option>
                                    <option value='user'>Ordinary User</option></select>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <input type='submit' value='Add'/>
                                </form>";
                                ?>
            <?php
                    if  (isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['sound']==1))
                    echo "
                    <div id = 'soundToggle'>
                          <form id = 'soundOffForm'>
                            <p> Sound is currently on. </p>
                            <center><input type = 'submit' value ='Turn Off Sound' /></center>
                          </form>
                    </div>
                        ";
                    else if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['sound']==0))
                    echo "
                    <div id = 'soundToggle'>
                          <form id = 'soundOnForm'>
                            <p> Sound is currently off. </p>
                            <center><input type = 'submit' value = 'Turn On Sound' /></center>
                          </form>
                    </div>
                        ";
                        ?>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
                echo "<center><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></center>";?>  

            <p class = "content"> This is a page that is a scrap work in progress. </p>


            <?php include("footer.php"); ?> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                // jQuery Document
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#soundOffForm").on('submit', function(event){
                        /*var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                        r.open("POST", "sessionsetter.php", true);
                        r.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return; 
                            console.log(r.responseText);
                        };
                        r.send("a=1&b=2&c=3");*/
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sessionsetter.php",
                            data: {
                                sound : '0',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                //alert("Sound toggled successfully: " + data);
                                $('#soundToggle').load(location.href + " #soundOnForm");

                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert("Error in processing request: " + data);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#soundOnForm").on('submit', function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sessionsetter.php",
                            data: {
                                sound : '1',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                //alert("Sound toggled successfully: " + data);
                                $('#soundToggle').load(location.href + " #soundOffForm");
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert("Error in processing request: " + data);

                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems to work the first time I either toggle the sound on or off with the corresponding submission form inside the div. However, the second time I do it the ENTIRE document is refreshed. Somehow `event.preventDefault()` is not taking place. I have to admit, I'm still a jQuery rookie. Can someone please explain to me what I need to do to perhaps reattach the divs to their corresponding events in my jQuery script?

Comment: I'm editing this again to include the whole code. Please don't hate...

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the contents of `#soundToggle`, the new form no longer has the old handlers attached to it. It's just a `form`, and wants to submit and replace the page, as forms do.

You'll want to use event delegation, to catch a submit on any existing *or future* forms with those `id`s:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#soundOffForm', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sessionsetter.php",
        data: {
            sound : '0',
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("Sound toggled successfully: " + data);
            $('#soundToggle').load(location.href + " #soundOnForm");

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Error in processing request: " + data);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('submit', '#soundOnForm', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sessionsetter.php",
        data: {
            sound : '1',
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("Sound toggled successfully: " + data);
            $('#soundToggle').load(location.href + " #soundOffForm");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Error in processing request: " + data);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks... do I need to keep this for the full document outside of document.ready()? Or does it go inside of that? Maybe use (this).on() for these function if it's inside document.ready()?

Comment: It can live in `document.ready()` or not. In this case, it won't really matter.

Comment: Okay, the reason I ask this is because now that I've changed the code the page just submits every time. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Hmm.  *Do* try moving it to `$(document).ready()`, if it's not already there. Other than that, not sure.

Comment: That's the thing, it IS inside $(document).ready(). Should I email you the full code? It's a little messy...

Comment: No. If more code needs to be seen to replicate/understand the problem, it belongs *in the question*.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the additional comment, I extended the JQuery code. If that doesn't tell anything, I'll edit the post to include the whole index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Paul had really helped narrow the problem down. I've finally figured it out.

You still need to use $("#selected").submit() to actually trigger the form submission. So the question is, how do we target the selector when it changes?

Of course, JQuery allows multiple selectors. SO, if you're going to replace a div with such an id with a div of a different id, use $("body #selected"). That will allow the DOM to constantly check the children so that the submission is triggered.

This one's a strange one. Hope it helps people out there.

Comment: Well never mind! This doesn't appear to work either. I'm stumped. Ready to use a completely different approach.